# Anybody can help me please to present this table better? It does look nice table. Any idea?

Tags: tables

[image]

```
   \begin{table}[H]
    \label{ch:four:t6}

    \centering\small
    \begin{tabular}{c c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 

    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chunk Range} (0.5sec./chunk) &\it 1-2 &\it 2-3 &\it 3-4 &\it 4-5 &\it 5-6 &\it 6-7&\it 7-8&\it 8-9&\it 9-10 \\ \hline
    \bf Content & \bf Method & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\bf quality-layers and views}\\

    \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{BookArrival}} & Proposed VR &- &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^8$ &$L_{e}^9$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\
    %&- &- &$L_{e}^7$ &$L_{e}$ &- &$L_{e}$ &- &- &- &- &$L_{e}$ &- &-
    & VS    &-  &-  &$L_{e}$    &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{8}$ &$L_{e}^{8}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{Newspaper}} & Proposed VR   &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{3}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

    & VS    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{5}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{ChampagneTower}} & Proposed VR  &-  &-  &-  &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{39}$ &$L_{e}^{40}$ &$L_{e}^{38,39}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

    & VS    &-  &-  &-  &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{38}$ &$L_{e}^{38}$ &$L_{e}^{38,40}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{Caf\'{e}}} & Proposed VR    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^2$ &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

    & VS    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^1$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{\texttt{PoznanStreet}} & Proposed VR &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^4$  &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$    &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{4,5}$ &$L_{e}$ \\

    & VS &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^4$  &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$    &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{2,4}$ &$L_{e}$\\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Try to avoid vertical lines. Use booktabs package (along with the description there). Think about grouping the columns or reducing their number.

Comment: You don't even mention what the table components represent. Without context and/or the motivation behind your current choices, this question is of low quality.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: How wide is your text block? If you the LaTeX default, the table is much too wide to fit. The first and second header rows seem to be in reverse order. Is that the case?

Comment: @Cagri - Adding a picture is *not* what you were asked to do.

Comment: @Mico I do not know the text block. this document is based on the template. It shows fine, when I compile it, but i think, we can change it a bit and present result well. This is just I want, I am not good at latex!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't show fine. The choice of fonts is arbitrary, the alignment of the first column should be left and the “missing value” marker should be an en-dash.

Putting the data into boxes doesn't help the reader in finding them. Better avoiding vertical rules that add nothing and hinder reading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\Le}{L_{e}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\footnotesize
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2.1pt}% computed “a posteriori”

\begin{tabular}{@{} l c *{9}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Content} & \bfseries Method &
   \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Quality-layers and views}*}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-11}
 && 1--2 & 2--3 & 3--4 & 4--5 & 5--6 & 6--7& 7--8& 8--9 & 9--10 \\

\midrule

BookArrival
  & Proposed VR & -- & --  &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^8$ &$\Le^9$ &$\Le$ & -- \\
\addlinespace
  & VS          & -- & --  &$\Le$    &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^{8}$ &$\Le^{8}$ &$\Le$ & -- \\

\midrule

Newspaper
  & Proposed VR & --  & --  & --  & -- &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^{3}$ &$\Le$ & -- \\
\addlinespace
  & VS          & --  & --  & --  & -- &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^{5}$ &$\Le$ & -- \\

\midrule

ChampagneTower
  & Proposed VR  & --  & --  & --  &$\Le$ &$\Le^{39}$ &$\Le^{40}$ &$\Le^{38,39}$ &$\Le$ & -- \\
\addlinespace
  & VS           & --  & --  & --  &$\Le$ &$\Le^{38}$ &$\Le^{38}$ &$\Le^{38,40}$ &$\Le$ & -- \\

\midrule

Caf\'{e}
  & Proposed VR & --  & --  & --  & -- &$\Le^3$ &$\Le^2$ &$\Le^3$ &$\Le$ & -- \\
\addlinespace
  & VS          & --  & --  & --  & -- &$\Le^3$ &$\Le^3$ &$\Le^1$ &$\Le$ & -- \\

\midrule

PoznanStreet
  & Proposed VR &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^4$  &$\Le^{3,4,5}$    &$\Le^{3,4,5}$ &$\Le^{3,4,5}$ &$\Le^{4,5}$ &$\Le$ \\
\addlinespace
  & VS          &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le$ &$\Le^4$  &$\Le^{3,4,5}$    &$\Le^{3,4,5}$ &$\Le^{3,4,5}$ &$\Le^{2,4}$ &$\Le$\\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{* Chunk Range (0.5\,sec/chunk)}

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Depending on the width of your text block you'll have to modify the reduction to `\tabcolsep`. Comment the line, see how much the table is overfull (look at the message in the `log` file) and divide the excess by 20, the number of available intercolumn spaces.

[image]

Comment: Why `\addlinespace` between “consecutive” rows? Isn't `\addlinespace` intended more as a *substitute* of the `\midrule`s here?

Comment: Is there any reason to use `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf{}`.

Comment: It's instructive to compare the strategies we chose to make the table fit in the text block: You selected `\footnotesize`, allowing `\tabcolsep` to be set at a fairly generous `3.9pt`. In contrast, I went with `\small` to keep the material as easily legible as possible, but then had to set `\tabcolsep` to a much smaller value (`2pt`) in order to make the table fit in the text block. Both strategies have their merits, naturally.

Comment: As the "method" is always the same is enough specify that method in the caption or in the main text. It make no sense waste a wide column for that.  This way you can have a big `\tabcolsep` and a big font without juggling.

Answer (score 11):

I will admit up front to not having the foggiest idea what the information content of this table may be. But it does seem to be the case that the order of the two header rows is reversed. I also don't see a need to set the sub-header items in italics. (I don't perceive an urgent need for the `\bf` and `\texttt` directives either, but I've left them in.) I did get rid of the `\multirow` directives, though.

I also got rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines, and replaced the remaining `\hline`s with macros provided by the `booktabs` package. But, most importantly, I've reduced the value of parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace, so that the table may actually fit inside the width of the text block.

A separate comment: You seem to be in the habit of providing a `\label` instruction for each `table`, but no `\caption`. Unfortunately, without a caption there's no point providing a `\label` with this table. LaTeX associate each `\label` with a counter variable. (`\caption` increments the counter called `table`.) Importantly, if the `\caption` statement is missing, the `\label` will become associated -- incorrectly! -- with whatever counter was incremented most recently. This could be an equation, a subsection, a theorem, etc. Probably not your objective, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\caption{A table} \label{ch:four:t6}
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l *{9}{c}@{}} 
\toprule
\bfseries Content & \bfseries Method & \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{\bfseries Quality layers and views}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-11}
Chunk Range &(0.5\,sec/chunk) & 1--2 & 2--3 & 3--4 & 4--5 & 5--6 & 6--7& 7--8& 8--9& 9--10 \\ 
\midrule
\texttt{BookArrival} & Proposed VR &- &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^8$ &$L_{e}^9$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\
%&- &- &$L_{e}^7$ &$L_{e}$ &- &$L_{e}$ &- &- &- &- &$L_{e}$ &- &-
& VS    &-  &-  &$L_{e}$    &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{8}$ &$L_{e}^{8}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \addlinespace
\texttt{Newspaper} & Proposed VR   &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{3}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

& VS    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{5}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \addlinespace
\texttt{ChampagneTower} & Proposed VR  &-  &-  &-  &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{39}$ &$L_{e}^{40}$ &$L_{e}^{38,39}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

& VS    &-  &-  &-  &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^{38}$ &$L_{e}^{38}$ &$L_{e}^{38,40}$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \addlinespace
\texttt{Caf\'{e}} & Proposed VR    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^2$ &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\

& VS    &-  &-  &-  &- &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^3$ &$L_{e}^1$ &$L_{e}$ &- \\ \addlinespace
\texttt{PoznanStreet} & Proposed VR &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^4$  &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$    &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{4,5}$ &$L_{e}$ \\

& VS &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}$ &$L_{e}^4$  &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$    &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{3,4,5}$ &$L_{e}^{2,4}$ &$L_{e}$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```